# How can I resolve this promise?

Tags: promise, discord, discord.js, bots

This is my code:

```
    collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
        console.log(reaction);
        if (!user.bot) {
            let role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === ra[emojiarray.indexOf(reaction)]);
            await reaction.message.guild.members.fetch(user).roles.add(role);
        }
    });
```

Except I get the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`. I was told to resolve the promise, and I tried, but I guess I didn't do it right. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to `await` the fetch of the user, and then add the role to the user.

```js
collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
        console.log(reaction);
        if (!user.bot) {
            let role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === ra[emojiarray.indexOf(reaction)]);
            let userMember = await reaction.message.guild.members.fetch(user);
            userMember.roles.add(role);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hm. I got `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'user' before initialization`

Comment: Sorry about that! I updated the variable name because I too quickly added that `user` variable.  I changed my added `user` variable to `userMember` so it didn't conflict with the parameter.

Comment: Haha no problem! Still getting an error, but I don't think this is the issue anymore. You're the best, thank you!!

Comment: I might be able to help you better by seeing the full code. You can use a site like replit.com to host the NodeJS code and share it here.